# SELF-JOIN discarding true CROSS JOIN rows

Tags: sql, mariadb, self-join, cross-join

I have the following query;

What I get is tickets information. I use self-join to obtain the requester and the assignee in the same row:

```
SELECT z.id AS TICKET, z.name AS Subject, reqs.name AS Requester, techs.name AS Assignee,
       e.name AS Entity,DATE_FORMAT(tt.date,'%y%-%m%-%d') AS DATE,
       DATE_FORMAT(tt.date,'%T') AS HOUR,
       CASE WHEN z.priority = 6 THEN 'Mayor' WHEN z.priority = 5 THEN 'Muy urgente' WHEN z.priority = 4 THEN 'Urgente'WHEN z.priority = 3 THEN 'Mediana' WHEN z.priority = 2 THEN 'Baja' WHEN z.priority =1 THEN 'Muy baja' END AS Priority,
       c.name AS Category, i.name AS Department
FROM glpi_tickets_users tureq
JOIN glpi_tickets_users tutech ON  tureq.tickets_id = tutech.tickets_id
JOIN glpi_users AS reqs  ON tureq.users_id = reqs.id
JOIN glpi_users AS techs ON tutech.users_id = techs.id
JOIN glpi_tickets z ON z.id = tureq.tickets_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN glpi_tickettasks tt ON z.id = tt.tickets_id
LEFT JOIN glpi_itilcategories i ON z.itilcategories_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN glpi_usercategories c ON c.id = reqs.usercategories_id
INNER JOIN glpi_entities e ON z.entities_id = e.id
WHERE (tureq.id < tutech.id AND tureq.type < tutech.type) OR
      (tureq.id < tutech.id AND tureq.users_id = tutech.users_id) OR
      (tureq.id = tutech.id AND tureq.users_id = tutech.users_id)
```

The problem is that I get something like that:

```
1   Report jdoe        jdoe        Development   16-06-07  11:56:17        Mediana Software    Mkt
1   Report jdoe        fwilson     Development   16-06-07  11:56:17        Mediana Software    MKt
1   Report fwilson     fwilson     Development   16-06-07  11:56:17        Mediana Software    Mkt
2   Task11 gwilliams   gwilliams   Ops           16-06-08  12:00:00        ALTA    Hardware    Def
3   Task12 gwilliams   gwilliams   Ops           16-06-08  12:01:00        ALTA    Hardware    Def
```

I don't want first and third row because is a CROSS JOIN result. Second row is OK, because jdoe is a requester and fwilson an assignee.

The problem is that sometimes requester and assignee are the same, eg: he creates a ticket for a task that himself will do. For example, 4th and 5th rows are OK.

So, how should I do to make a difference for those distinct cases, i.e.: I need to include:

`tureq.id = tech.id AND req.users_id = tech.users.id`

BUT NOT IF ALREADY EXISTS
`tureq.id = tech.id AND req.users_id <> tech.users_id`

**Update**

The main problem is that a user can assign to himself a ticket:

```
 SELECT * from glpi_tickets_users WHERE type = 2  GROUP BY tickets_id HAVING COUNT(users_id)<2 limit 3;
+----+------------+----------+------+------------------+-------------------+
| id | tickets_id | users_id | type | use_notification | alternative_email |
+----+------------+----------+------+------------------+-------------------+
|  1 |          2 |       12 |    2 |                1 | NULL              |
|  3 |          6 |       13 |    2 |                1 | NULL              |
|  7 |          8 |       14 |    2 |                1 | NULL              |
+----+------------+----------+------+------------------+-------------------+
```

**Update 2:**

It was a human mistake. The problem was really not about self-assigned tickets. Rather it was either that some tickets had not Requester or had Requester but still had not any resolver assigned.
I've found

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  A query with 9 tables in it is unlikely to be minimal; if it is, there'd be explanation of how you demonstrated that it was minimal.

Comment: I think you'd need to pivot the glpi_tickets_users  before joining to it so you don't have the multiple joins giveing you the cross join like results.

Comment: So there can be many users per ticket and it's like a chain numbered by type? I.e. type 1 is requester for assignee type 2 and type 2 themselves is requester to assignee type 3? At least this is how I understand your query. Can you show sample data with at least three persons in a ticket plus the desired result?

Comment: @thorsten-kettner Yes there can be many users per ticket. Type 1 is requester and type2 is assignee. But it happens that a same user can open a ticket and to assign to himself, that's right. But I'd wan to exclude cross joins.

Comment: Only type 1 and type 2? No other types? And if a user assignes to themselves there are two entries for the same user, one with type 1 and one with type 2? There are always exactly two entries per ticket, one with type 1, one with type 2?

Comment: There are one type more 3: Observer, but I don't need it. So yes we can say that there are always two entries.

Comment: Which version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner mariadb-server-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64

Comment: Okay, so no window functions available. Now answer my question whether a self-assignment has type 1 or 2 or sometimes 1 and sometimes 2 and I can think of a solution.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Please read my update 2. Always a requester has type 1 and resolver has type 2. No matter the user.

Answer (score 3):

As there are always the two types per ticket you are interested in, you can simply select the according records, so as to get requester and assignee per ticket.

```
select 
  t.id as ticket, 
  t.name as subject, 
  requester.name as requester, 
  assignee.name as assignee,
  e.name as entity,
  date_format(tt.date,'%y%-%m%-%d') as date,
  date_format(tt.date,'%T') as hour,
  case t.priority 
    when 6 then 'Mayor' 
    when 5 then 'Muy urgente' 
    when 4 then 'Urgente'
    when 3 then 'Mediana' 
    when 2 then 'Baja' 
    when 1 then 'Muy baja'
  end as priority,
  uc.name as category,
  ic.name as department
from glpi_tickets t
join glpi_entities e on e.id = t.entities_id
join 
(
  select tu.tickets_id, u.name, u.usercategories_id 
  from glpi_tickets_users tu
  join glpi_users u on u.id = users_id
  where tu.type = 1
) requester on requester.tickets_id = t.id
join 
(
  select tu.tickets_id, u.name 
  from glpi_tickets_users tu
  join glpi_users u on u.id = users_id
  where tu.type = 2
) assignee on assignee.tickets_id = t.id
left join glpi_itilcategories ic on ic.id = t.itilcategories_id
left join glpi_usercategories uc on uc.id = requester.usercategories_id;
left outer join glpi_tickettasks tt on tt.tickets_id = t.id
```

The only thing I wonder is: There can be several ticket tasks per ticket. So what do you want to do then? Have one line per ticket task in your results? This is what the query does. Only, it looks queer that your result rows don't contain any information on the tasks except for the dates, so you may have many, many lines with the same data, only with different dates. So maybe, you'd rather want the first or last date per ticket. To get the last date per ticket, you'd replace the last line in the query with:

```
left outer join
(
  select tickets_id, max(date) as date
  from glpi_tickettasks
  group by tickets_id
) tt on tt.tickets_id = t.id
```

And you probably want to add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: you don't need the sub-queries if you add the requirement (eg `and requester.type = 1` to the join statement

Comment: @thorsten-kettner I need to sum the hours by each tasks.  It's a nice approach, but, the main issue is that when is a "self-assigned" ticket the user type is the same.

Comment: I've added to the first sub-query  `OR tu.type = 2 GROUP BY tu.tickets_id HAVING COUNT(tu.id)=1` but it won't work either.

Comment: @Hogan: You are right. I thought with a subquery it becomes very readable which data belongs to requester and which to assignee, but it doesn't make much difference and many may prefer simple joins as you suggest.

Comment: @sebelk: So you didn't answer my question properly. Here is the question again: "And if a user assignes to themselves there are two entries for the same user, one with type 1 and one with type 2?" Now you say this is not the case, so are there two entries with type 1 then? Or two with type 2? Or only one entry? (Anyway it makes queries more complicated, as you don't store data consistently, as I thought you did.)

Comment: And how would you sum the hours? I see a date (containing a time obviously), where I would expect a start time plus an end time or a duration. How do you know how long a task takes?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Sorry, if a user assign to himself, there is only one entry.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner There is afield called actiontime from where I sum hours.

Comment: One entry with type 1? Or one entry with type2? Or sometimes type 1 and sometimes type 2? (You do notice that you could have got a correct solution three hours ago, had you only answered my questions properly? You are always answering one part and leave another unanswered, so I have to ask again. You should learn how to read questions and answer them.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add more qualifiers to your joins for example

```
JOIN glpi_tickets_users tutech ON  tureq.tickets_id = tutech.tickets_id and tutech.type = 2
```